# PyQt5 retrieving frames before/after current frame

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtmultimedia, qmediaplayer, qvideowidget

I'm new to PyQt and I'm trying to create a videoplayer. When the user screenshots a certain frame, I should be able to retrieve 5 frames prior to the current frame and another 5 frames after the current frame. So far I'm only able to retrieve the current frame and I'm having a hard time figuring out which part of the code to alter to store the previous frames and the after frames. Here's the complete code:

```
# PyQt5 Video player
#!/usr/bin/env python

from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir, Qt, QUrl, pyqtSignal, QPoint, QRect, QObject
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaContent, QMediaPlayer, QVideoFrame, QAbstractVideoSurface, QAbstractVideoBuffer, QVideoSurfaceFormat
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QFileDialog, QHBoxLayout, QLabel,
        QPushButton, QSizePolicy, QSlider, QStyle, QVBoxLayout, QWidget)
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QWidget, QPushButton, QAction
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon, QPainter, QImage
import sys
import os
import os.path as osp

class VideoFrameGrabber(QAbstractVideoSurface):
    frameAvailable = pyqtSignal(QImage)

    def __init__(self, widget: QWidget, parent: QObject):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.widget = widget
    def supportedPixelFormats(self, handleType):
        return [QVideoFrame.Format_ARGB32, QVideoFrame.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied,
                QVideoFrame.Format_RGB32, QVideoFrame.Format_RGB24, QVideoFrame.Format_RGB565,
                QVideoFrame.Format_RGB555, QVideoFrame.Format_ARGB8565_Premultiplied,
                QVideoFrame.Format_BGRA32, QVideoFrame.Format_BGRA32_Premultiplied, QVideoFrame.Format_BGR32,
                QVideoFrame.Format_BGR24, QVideoFrame.Format_BGR565, QVideoFrame.Format_BGR555,
                QVideoFrame.Format_BGRA5658_Premultiplied, QVideoFrame.Format_AYUV444,
                QVideoFrame.Format_AYUV444_Premultiplied, QVideoFrame.Format_YUV444,
                QVideoFrame.Format_YUV420P, QVideoFrame.Format_YV12, QVideoFrame.Format_UYVY,
                QVideoFrame.Format_YUYV, QVideoFrame.Format_NV12, QVideoFrame.Format_NV21,
                QVideoFrame.Format_IMC1, QVideoFrame.Format_IMC2, QVideoFrame.Format_IMC3,
                QVideoFrame.Format_IMC4, QVideoFrame.Format_Y8, QVideoFrame.Format_Y16,
                QVideoFrame.Format_Jpeg, QVideoFrame.Format_CameraRaw, QVideoFrame.Format_AdobeDng]

    def isFormatSupported(self, format):
        imageFormat = QVideoFrame.imageFormatFromPixelFormat(format.pixelFormat())
        size = format.frameSize()

        return imageFormat != QImage.Format_Invalid and not size.isEmpty() and \
               format.handleType() == QAbstractVideoBuffer.NoHandle

    def start(self, format: QVideoSurfaceFormat):
        imageFormat = QVideoFrame.imageFormatFromPixelFormat(format.pixelFormat())
        size = format.frameSize()

        if imageFormat != QImage.Format_Invalid and not size.isEmpty():
            self.imageFormat = imageFormat
            self.imageSize = size
            self.sourceRect = format.viewport()

            super().start(format)

            self.widget.updateGeometry()
            self.updateVideoRect()

            return True
        else:
            return False

    def stop(self):
        self.currentFrame = QVideoFrame()
        self.targetRect = QRect()

        super().stop()

        self.widget.update()

    def present(self, frame):
        if frame.isValid():
            cloneFrame = QVideoFrame(frame)
            cloneFrame.map(QAbstractVideoBuffer.ReadOnly)
            image = QImage(cloneFrame.bits(), cloneFrame.width(), cloneFrame.height(),
                           QVideoFrame.imageFormatFromPixelFormat(cloneFrame.pixelFormat()))
            self.frameAvailable.emit(image)  # this is very important
            cloneFrame.unmap()

        if self.surfaceFormat().pixelFormat() != frame.pixelFormat() or \
                self.surfaceFormat().frameSize() != frame.size():
            self.setError(QAbstractVideoSurface.IncorrectFormatError)
            self.stop()

            return False
        else:
            self.currentFrame = frame
            self.widget.repaint(self.targetRect)

            return True

    def updateVideoRect(self):
        size = self.surfaceFormat().sizeHint()
        size.scale(self.widget.size().boundedTo(size), Qt.KeepAspectRatio)

        self.targetRect = QRect(QPoint(0, 0), size)
        self.targetRect.moveCenter(self.widget.rect().center())

    def paint(self, painter):
        if self.currentFrame.map(QAbstractVideoBuffer.ReadOnly):
            oldTransform = self.painter.transform()

        if self.surfaceFormat().scanLineDirection() == QVideoSurfaceFormat.BottomToTop:
            self.painter.scale(1, -1)
            self.painter.translate(0, -self.widget.height())

        image = QImage(self.currentFrame.bits(), self.currentFrame.width(), self.currentFrame.height(),
                       self.currentFrame.bytesPerLine(), self.imageFormat)

        self.painter.drawImage(self.targetRect, image, self.sourceRect)

        self.painter.setTransform(oldTransform)

        self.currentFrame.unmap()

class VideoWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(VideoWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt Video Player Widget") 

        self.counter = 0
        self.mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer(None, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
        self.videoWidget = QVideoWidget()
        self.videoFrame = QVideoFrame()
        self.playButton = QPushButton()
        self.playButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.playButton.setIcon(self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPlay))
        self.playButton.clicked.connect(self.play)

        self.positionSlider = QSlider(Qt.Horizontal)
        self.positionSlider.setRange(0, 0)
        self.positionSlider.sliderMoved.connect(self.setPosition)

        self.errorLabel = QLabel()
        self.errorLabel.setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy.Preferred,
                QSizePolicy.Maximum)
        # Create new action
        openAction = QAction(QIcon('open.png'), '&Open', self)        
        openAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        openAction.setStatusTip('Open video')
        openAction.triggered.connect(self.openFile)

        # Create exit action
        exitAction = QAction(QIcon('quit.png'), '&Exit', self)        
        exitAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+Q')
        exitAction.setStatusTip('Exit application')
        exitAction.triggered.connect(self.exitCall)

        screenshotAction = QAction(QIcon('screenshot.png'), '&Screenshot', self)
        screenshotAction.setShortcut('Ctrl+S')
        screenshotAction.setStatusTip('Screenshot scenes')
        screenshotAction.triggered.connect(self.screenshotCall)

        # Create menu bar and add action
        menuBar = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = menuBar.addMenu('&File')
        #fileMenu.addAction(newAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(openAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(screenshotAction)
        fileMenu.addAction(exitAction)


        # Create a widget for window contents
        wid = QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(wid)

        # Create layouts to place inside widget
        controlLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        controlLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        controlLayout.addWidget(self.playButton)
        controlLayout.addWidget(self.positionSlider)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.videoWidget)
        layout.addLayout(controlLayout)
        layout.addWidget(self.errorLabel)

        # Set widget to contain window contents
        wid.setLayout(layout)


        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(self.videoWidget)
        self.mediaPlayer.stateChanged.connect(self.mediaStateChanged)
        self.mediaPlayer.positionChanged.connect(self.positionChanged)
        self.mediaPlayer.durationChanged.connect(self.durationChanged)
        self.mediaPlayer.error.connect(self.handleError)

    def openFile(self):
        fileName, _ = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open Movie",
                QDir.homePath())
        self.path = osp.dirname(str(fileName))
        if fileName != '':
            self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(
                    QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile(fileName)))
            self.playButton.setEnabled(True)

    def exitCall(self):
        sys.exit(app.exec_())

    def screenshotCall(self):
        #Call video frame grabber
        self.grabber = VideoFrameGrabber(self.videoWidget, self)
        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(self.grabber)
        self.mediaPlayer.pause()
        self.grabber.frameAvailable.connect(self.process_frame)
        self.errorLabel.setText("Taking a screenshot of image "+str(self.counter)+" ....")
        self.mediaPlayer.play()
        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(self.videoWidget)

    def play(self):
        if self.mediaPlayer.state() == QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            self.mediaPlayer.pause()
        else:
            self.mediaPlayer.play()

    def mediaStateChanged(self, state):
        if self.mediaPlayer.state() == QMediaPlayer.PlayingState:
            self.playButton.setIcon(
                    self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPause))
        else:
            self.playButton.setIcon(
                    self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.SP_MediaPlay))

    def positionChanged(self, position):
        self.positionSlider.setValue(position)

    def durationChanged(self, duration):
        self.positionSlider.setRange(0, duration)

    def setPosition(self, position):
        self.mediaPlayer.setPosition(position)

    def handleError(self):
        self.playButton.setEnabled(False)
        self.errorLabel.setText("Error: " + self.mediaPlayer.errorString())

    def process_frame(self, image):
        # Save image here
        filename = "screenshot" + str(self.counter).zfill(6)
        self.path = 'C:/Desktop/temp'
        image.save(self.path+'/{}.png'.format(str(filename)))
        self.counter = self.counter+1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    player = VideoWindow()
    player.resize(720, 480)
    player.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'm thinking of retrieving the current frame number and creating loops to retrieve the before and after frames and then send them to `process_frame` for saving, but I'm not sure how to implement that because as of now, I'm still having a hard time grasping the principles behind the video frame grabber.

Comment: The current frame you are using in process_frame, where do you want to use the previous and subsequent frames?

Comment: @eyllanesc I need to be able to retrieve the screenshots for previous and subsequent frames when screenshotCall is triggered. so i was thinking of retrieving the frame number or millisec of the current frame from process_frame and then creating a function to get the previous frame and another for the subsequent frame using that input from process_frame so i could implement them as screenshotCall is called.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few options.

First is to seek the video to the frames you need using `QMediaPlayer.setPosition`, then use the grabber you have already implemented to grab the current frame. Then you'd restore the position.

In reality, this is difficult to implement, since you need to know precise frame times, which is something that PyQT doesn't offer as part of their API.

To obtain frame times, you could use [FFMS2](https://github.com/FFMS/ffms2) library and its [Python bindings](https://pypi.org/project/ffms/):

```py
import ffms

source_file = "test/x264.mkv"
vsource = ffms.VideoSource(source_file)
print("Frames:", vsource.properties.NumFrames)
print("Times:", vsource.track.timecodes)
```

This is where the other solution kicks in. If you use FFMS2 anyway, why even use the media player to obtain the frames? You can just use FFMS2 directly:

```
>>> frame = vsource.get_frame(0)
>>> frame.EncodedWidth, frame.EncodedHeight
(128, 72)
>>> frame.planes[0]
array([16, 16, 16, ..., 16, 16, 16], dtype=uint8)
```

You input the frame number and receive a `numpy` array that you can convert into an actual image with library such as PIL or scikit-image. So you only need to convert current stream position to the frame number. To do it, you can query the `vsource.track.timecodes` variable and find the index of the closest frame number. To do it fast, you can use divide-and-conquer technique (the builtin Python `bisect` module).

---

Note that you should load the `ffms.VideoSource` once, when you select the video, since it may take a bit of time to index the time and frame information and you don't want the UI to lag when the user chooses to do a screenshot. To further speed up things, you could also cache the indexing information, if you need to reopen the file often. Manual indexing is covered in FFMS2 documentation.

Comment: hi @rr-, thanks for this! i'm trying it right now. do you happen to know how to retrieve the frame number of the current frame? i can't seem to find it in any documentation

Comment: It's described near "So you only need to convert current stream position to the frame number. "